# Action to change a property of a sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to create a sequence to actions, at the end of which I want to set the visibility of the sprite to false.

Eg:

mySprite->setVisible(false);

Is there any action I can create to do this ? I cannot use a callback, because callbacks do not allow you to use "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callbacks for this purpose by using lambda functions and [capturing `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22930214/5052095) but if you don't want to do that you can run a `FadeOut` action with a time of `0.0`

Comment: FYI: FadeOut changes the opacity, but the GPU still draws it unless you set the visibility to false.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using a callback.